# ReferenceError: ShadowRoot is not defined

Tags: reactjs

Selecting non-date field value by button

```
ReferenceError: ShadowRoot is not defined

    );
 
   return render(ui, { wrapper: Wrapper, ...renderOptions });
               ^
};
```

I am using below libraries

"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^6.1.3",
"@testing-library/react": "^14.0.0",
"@types/react": "^18.2.24",
"@types/react-dom": "^18.2.7",
"react-dom": "^18.2.0",
"react": "^18.2.0",

Comment: Please add more code, and maybe fix your formatting a  little bit.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.